# How to pass parameters

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I have a .NET Maui app that i am working on.  It is a shell app.  Previously, I would pass parameters in Xamarin to a new class/content page by passing the params as a constructor, setting a property on the class, or using MessagingCenter as necessary.  I can still send a message, I get that.  How would I pass the params as a constructor or as a parameter?

Previously, I would do something like.  I'm really wondering what I do now to do something simple like this.  How would I pass multiple params?  How do I do this easily? TIA.

```
public partial class CreateUser : ContentPage
{
    public string GivenName{ get; set; }
    public CreateUser(string Name)
    {
       GivenName = Name;
    }
............more code.......
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

Answer (score 1):

**1)** There is an [introductory tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/tutorials/notes-app/) that guides you through creating a simple Maui app. On tutorial page [Customize the app shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/tutorials/notes-app/?tutorial-step=2), we learn that the default Maui template creates an AppShell. Thus, uses AppShell navigation; see link in Jason's comment on the question.

**2)** If you DON'T want to use AppShell, then in `App.xaml.cs`, find line:

```cs
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

Replace that line with either a NavigationPage:

```cs
MainPage = new NavigationPage();
```

OR directly create your first page:

```cs
MainPage = new MyMainPage();
```

Whichever you are accustomed to doing in XForms.