# How do I get data from another page in Maui ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have ContentPage A, which has a button which navigates to ContentPage B (using Shell.Current.GoToAsync in it's VM).

Page B allows the user to select a file from the device.

How do I get back to Page A and tell that page what file was selected?

Thanks

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73878435/2794280

Answer (score -1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73594726/how-to-pass-parameters) is pretty similar to yours, you have pretty much all the infos [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#pass-data). Shell is URI based, contraty to NavigationPage which is hierarchical (based on a stack), if you want to pass more complexe objects you have to use NavigationPages or dependency injections.

So you can just use in `PageB` :

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"PageA?fileName={fileName}");
```

Just be cautious of [BakeButtonBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#back-button-behavior) if you want to have a default file for example.

Comment: The above does not answer the question.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas I don't see where it doesn't, if you want to pass data between page while using shell you can only pass string based parameters. In the link I gave it's [described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#process-navigation-data-using-a-single-method) how you can get those parameters inside a viewmodel. Is there something that is not clear in my answer ?

Comment: The question is about to pass a parameter back to the previous page. Your answer is passing a parameter to a new page.

Comment: That's how Shell navigation work, it's URI based so there is no stack. In other words there is no "going back" you just navigate to routes as in a navigator. So to navigate from B to A (going to the previous page) there is no other way that I know of than GoToAsync (I don't even think there is a history in Shell ...), so yeah that suck but that's how you should do it. I would be happy to see an answer that say I am wrong :)